# Include files for a plugin not including

Tags: plugins, include

I have a plugin which I need to include a file in but it doesn't include.

Here's the example of the tree:

```
plugin folder
    /themes
    /folder2
    /somefiles
    /includeme.php
```

Within themes is

```
/default
/theme2
```

Then within each theme are the files
E.g.

```
Header.php
Footer.php
```

The plugin simply switches these themes via the admin.

Now in header.php I added

```
<?php include('includeme.php'); ?>
```

Which didn't work.

A friend told me since it is two levels up the tree I should actually add

```
<?php include('/../../includeme.php'); ?>.
```

Both didn't work.

I googled something that said to try.

```
<?php include([$_SERVER]['DOCUMENT_ROOT']'./wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/includeme.php'); ?>.
```

That also didn't work.
This is a basic plugin which renders theme based on admin settings combined with user agent detection.

Any suggestions or further code required?

The code is located at http://pastebin.com/A3buAA0R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main plugin file, use [`plugin_dir_path`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path) to define a constant that you can then use in all of your includes. see the example on the above codex page.

```
// define the constant in your main plugin file
define( 'MYPLUGINNAME_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );
```

then, to include your file:

```
include MYPLUGINNAME_PATH . 'includeme.php';
```

Comment: I would also mention `plugin_dir_url` since it seems like he will be storing some assets for the front end in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!!!!

I'm pretty amateur and have been struggling for days.
It works perfectly!!!

Comment: You should **not use a constant**, that would pollute the global namespace. Just use a function or a variable.

Comment: So when I need to include a php file in the frontend of a plugin, should I use plugin_dir_path with init as the hook? Thank-you.