# PHP: How to access db the right way in plugin?

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax

I thought I would find an answer to my question on the internet but I was not able to. This is not a big question, but as it is my first plugin, I want to make sure that everything is right before submitting.

What I am doing is adding a link to navigation menu depending on a value that admin selects from a settings panel in dashboard. I am accessing db in my custom javascript to add data to tables (in admin dashboard) and then fetching that data in another php script using "wp_nav_menu_items" filter.

I used

```
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'accessDB', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

to get hold of `admin-ajax.php` path. I then send my ajax calls to url referred by `accessDB.ajaxurl`. This part is working fine. And I think this is the right way to make ajax calls in Wordpress plugin. If not please correct me.

The second part is where I have to get the value from db. This is the value I need in a wordpress filter hook `wp_nav_menu_items`. And this is how it goes:

```
function add_custom_menu_link($items, $args) {

    global $wpdb;
    $row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "custom_table");

    if (count($row) > 0) {
        return $items . "<li class='menu-item'><a href='" . $row->url . "' target='_blank'>Custom Link</li>";
    } else {
        return $items;
    }
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_custom_menu_link', 10, 2);
```

So my question is that, am I doing it the right way, or do I have to use cURL to get the data by using `admin-ajax.php`? Or is there any other way that I am missing?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand if it works for you or not.

For me the code is **not** wrong, maybe can be optimized.

For the ajax request, if it is made in the backend, yo do not need to pass the ajax url using `wp_localize_script`. From WP 2.8 a global variable `ajaxurl` is defined to be used in ajax calls in the admin area.
So you can delete the `wp_localize_script` and use directly `ajaxurl` in the javascript.

Second optimization in the db request. Now it works, (or at least it should for me) but if you need only the variable `$row->url` you can use `$wpdb->get_var`, like so:

```
$url = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT url FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "custom_table");
if ( filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ) {
    return $items . "<li class='menu-item'><a href='" . esc_url($url) . "' target='_blank'>Custom Link</li>";
} else {
   return $items;
}
```

What is strange here is the missing of a 'WHERE' clause in your SQL. Seems you save only one value in a custom table. If so, is much better using the standard options table and using `get_option` / `update_option` to get and save the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know that Wordpress had a global variable for ajax calls.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik. You're welcome. Remember that it is only in admin area. In frontent you still pass the url like you do in posted code.

Comment: Does Wordpress allow to add a custom variable to options table? I mean can I store a variable like `update_option('my_custom_message', 'Hello World')`?

Comment: Of course. you can also use `update_option('my_custom_message', array('Hello', 'World'))` see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) @Jehanzeb.Malik

Comment: Just another small question. I also want to `include` another php file in my main plugin file. Do I simply use `include_once` at the top of file. Or is there action hook that I should use?

Comment: See the accepted answer of [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/68111/include-files-for-a-plugin-not-including)