# issues including a file from a plugin directory

Tags: directory, paths

I have a processForm.php *in theme directory* that does what it says. I am trying to **include a file** (which i need in order to run a specific function in processform.php) from a plugin directory and have been unable to do so. As suggested in [first solution in this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7398/how-to-include-php-files-in-plugins-the-correct-way) I tried :

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'test-plugin/needed_file.php');
```

I was pretty sure this would work but unfortunately it throw a warning like so :

```
Warning: include(/home2/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxx/test-plugin/needed_file.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

---

As said earlier the processForm.php lies in the theme directory and I have no issues anywhere else, calling files within the template directory. If this may help, there is alos a constant defined for this particular plugin's path which goes like this :

```
define('WPFP_PATH', plugins_url() . '/test-plugin');
```

So in accordance to a solution suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/68111/include-files-for-a-plugin-not-including),  I tried using code below :

```
include(WPFP_PATH . '/needed_file.php');
```

Unfortunately it throws three types of warning :

First warning :

```
http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

Second warning :

```
failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in....
```

Third warning :

```
Failed opening 'http://awesomeness.com/wp-content/plugins/test-plugin/needed_file.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in.....
```

> So the bottomline is How do I include this file into my
>   processForm.php ( which is in root of theme directory).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `plugin_dir_path` has an misleading name, it doesn't include a file from plugin directory, it just include a file from the same directory of the file passed as argument.

When you call

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'test-plugin/needed_file.php');
```

from a file in theme directory, you are just trying to include a file from theme directory too, because `__FILE__` constant always contain the path of file in which the statement is wrote.

The second way you try is the right one, but when you define `WPFP_PATH` you should use the **path** of the file, not the url, because a  lot of systems for security reasons have the including of urls disabled.

So you first have to put in main plugin file (the one that contain plugin headers)

```
define( 'WPFP_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
```

and thene in the theme

```
include( WPFP_PATH . 'needed_file.php' );
```

will work.

Note that the file is wrote without leading slash, because `plugin_dir_path` return the path with trailing slash.

However, once `WPFP_PATH`  is in the global namespace you should check if `defined` and/or maybe use a function to return the path, something like

```
function wpfp_get_path() {
  return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
}
```

and then in theme `include( wpfp_get_path() . 'needed_file.php' );`

Comment: "_when you define WPFP_PATH you should use the path of the file, not the url_" this suggestion worked. Although to my surprise I had it working with something as simple as `include ('wp-content/plugins/test-plugin/needed_file.php');`

Comment: You're welcome @gurung the include you wrote in comments *can* work, but relative path should always be avoided they are not very reliable